# Unable to resolve the error member function getrows() in fiverr script after uploading a project to site

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have uploaded fiverr script on my server and uploaded databases there, after installation the site runs good.
after i have uploaded a project to it i am getting this error continuously on the index page.

Here is the url: http://jobbyu.com/

this is the error which i am getting.

```
Warning: Division by zero in /home/xxx/public_html/index.php on line 116

Fatal error: Call to a member function getrows() on a non-object in /home/xxx/public_html/index.php on line 126
```

this is the code of index.php

```
106   if ($abc > 0)
107  {
108     if($executequery1->fields['total']<=$config[maximum_results])
109     {
110         $total = $executequery1->fields['total'];
111     }
112     else
113      {
114         $total = $config[maximum_results];
115      }
116     $toppage = ceil($total/$config['items_per_page_new']);
117     if($toppage==0)
118     {
119         $xpage=$toppage+1;
120     }
121     else
122     {
123         $xpage = $toppage;
124     }
125     $executequery2 = $conn->Execute($query2);
126     $posts = $executequery2->getrows();
127     $beginning=$pagingstart+1;
128     $ending=$pagingstart+$executequery2->recordcount();
129     $pagelinks="";
130     $k=1;
131     $theprevpage=$currentpage-1;
132     $thenextpage=$currentpage+1;
```

thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your config file, probably your variable `$config['items_per_page_new']` it's 0 so the calculus will be total_pages_value divided by 0 which throw an error.

PS: The url doesn't work anymore.